# when i use openaiAPI, a error such as "APIConnectionError: Connection error."

Tags: node.js, openai-api

`''file:///......../node_modules/openai/core.mjs:285             throw new APIConnectionError(cause: response);`

`APIConnectionError: Connection error.     at OpenAI.makeRequest (file:///......../node_modules/openai/core.mjs:285:19)     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)     at async main (file:///......../openai.js:6:22) {   status: undefined,   headers: undefined,   error: undefined,   code: undefined,   param: undefined,   type: undefined,   cause: FetchError: request to https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 168.143.171.189:443       at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (........\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1501:11)       at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:518:28)       at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:495:9)       at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:530:35)       at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)       at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)       at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {     type: 'system',     errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',     code: 'ETIMEDOUT'   } }''`

I hope reseive the answer